# Create a sequence of sequences of different lengths

Tags: r, sequence

I have to create a sequence of large number (> 10,000) of sequences of different lengths. I only know the lengths of these sequences in a vector form.

```
length_v <- c(2,3,4,4,2,6,11,75...................)
```

Each sequence starts from 1 and moves forward in steps of 1. And in the final sequence (combined one), each sequence has to appear one after the other, they can't be jumbled up.

A small demonstrating example is below:

I have say 4 sequences of length 2, 3, 4, 6 respectively.

```
s1 <- seq(1, 2)  # 1,2
s2 <- seq(1, 3)  # 1,2,3
s3 <- seq(1, 4)  # 1,2,3,4
s4 <- seq(1, 6)  # 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Final sequence will be

```
final <- c(s1,s2,s3,s4) **# the order has to be this only. No compromise here.**
```

I can't do this with > 10,000 sequences which would be very inefficient. Is there any simpler way of doing this?

Comment: `final <- unlist(mapply(seq, c(1,1,1,1), c(2,3,4,6)))` do every part sequence starts with `from=1` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `sequence`

```
sequence(length_v)
#[1] 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

#### data

```
length_v <- c(2,3,4,6)
```

Answer (score 4):

example:

```
unlist(sapply(c(2,3,4,6), seq, from=1))
```

so for you it will be:

```
unlist(sapply(length_v, seq, from=1))
```